# Create Wizard with MVVM Pattern - Databinding and GUI Update not working

Tags: mvvm

I am creating a Wizard for automatic Report generating. Therefore the user enters a couple of Issues to the Mainwindow and after he finished, he can create an automatically filled report by clicking a button. Also he need to switch between the entered Issuses (Therefore I put the issues to a list of the Type "Compliant".

The MainWindow contains different controls, in which the user can enter some information.
All controls are binded to the Model like this way (example for a textbox):

```
Text="{Binding Path=SingleCompliant.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

"SingleCompliant" is an object of the ViewModel of the type "Compliant" (part of the Model), which contains all attributes needed for one Issue.

When I load the Application for the first time, everything works fine. 
But when I click on "SaveCompliantAndNext", the binding between "SingleCompliant" Object gets lost and the GUI is not updating. In this Method (raised by a command) I create a new SingleCompliant Object.
What do I need to do for getting a new Object with an empty gui, so the user can continue entereing the next Issue?

This is the ViewModel with implemented "PropertyChanged" Handling:

```
public class Compliant_ViewModel : ObservableCollection<Compliant>  //INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow Controls are binded to Attributes of this object 
    /// </summary>
    private Compliant _SingleCompliant;

    public ObservableCollection<Compliant> CompliantListReport
    {
        get { return _CompliantListReport; }
        private set { _CompliantListReport = value; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Beandstandungs-Objekt
    /// </summary>
    public Compliant SingleCompliant
    {
        get { return _SingleCompliant; }
        set
        { _SingleCompliant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SingleCompliant");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load next Compliant to the GUI
    /// </summary>
    public NextCompliant_Command NextCompliant_command { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Load previous Compliant to the GUI
    /// </summary>
    public PreviousCompliant_Command PreviousCompliant_Command { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Compliant_ViewModel()
    {
        SingleCompliant = new Compliant();
        CompliantListReport = new ObservableCollection<Compliant>();

        NextCompliant_command = new NextCompliant_Command(SaveCompliantAndNext);
        PreviousCompliant_Command = new PreviousCompliant_Command(LoadPreviousCompliant);
        CreateReport_Command = new CreateReport_Command(CreateReport);

    }

    public void SaveCompliantAndNext()
    {
        CompliantListReport.Add(SingleCompliant);
        // >>>>>   Not working - databinding get lost and gui not updating
        SingleCompliant = new Compliant();
    }

    public void LoadPreviousCompliant()
    {
        if (this.SingleCompliant.CompliantID > 0)
        { this.SingleCompliant = this.CompliantListReport[this.SingleCompliant.CompliantID - 1]; }
        else
        { this.SingleCompliant = this.CompliantListReport[0]; }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        { handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));  }
    }
}
```

This is the Model:

```
 public class Compliant : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        private set
        {
            _Text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    #region Konstruktoren
    public Compliant()
    { }

    #region Interface

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

    #endregion Interface
}
```

XAML:
Example for one Textbox:
`<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SingleCompliant.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="Text" />`

XAML Buttons to switch between the Compliants (Issues):

```
<!--Previous Compliant (Issue)-->
<Button x:Name="BtnBack_Compliant" Content="{DynamicResource Back}" Command="{Binding PreviousCompliant_Command}"/>
<!--Next Compliant (Issue)-->
<Button x:Name="BtnForeward_Compliant" Content="{DynamicResource Foreward}" Command="{Binding NextCompliant_command}" />
```

What do I make wrong?